# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un contador de aciertos en las operaciones?

Tags: c

Tengo que diseñar un programa que permita practicar 2 veces las sumas, restas, divisiones y multiplicaciones, mediante un menú donde elige la operación que desea practicar, captura dos números y escribe el resultado de cada operación y el programa le indica. Si es correcto si no es correcto le muestra el resultado correcto.

Al final le indica los aciertos que ha logrado en el ejercicio. Esto último es lo que me falta. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char opcion;
    int n1, n2, res, sum, rest, mul, div;

    do
    {
        printf( "\n   >>> CALCULADORA DE 10 EJERCICIOS DE 4 OPERACIONES BASICAS <<<" );
        printf( "\n\n ----- Eliga la operacion que quiere realizar. ----- ");
        printf( "\n\n   1. Suma.", 163 );
        printf( "\n   2. Resta.", 163 );
        printf( "\n   3. Multiplicacion.", 163 );
        printf( "\n   4. Division.", 163 );
        printf( "\n   5. Salir.\n" );

        /* Filtramos la opción elegida por el usuario */
        do
        {
            printf( "\n   Introduzca opci%cn (1-5): ", 162 );
            fflush( stdin );
            scanf( "%c", &opcion);

        } while ( opcion < '1' || opcion > '5' );
        /* La opción sólo puede ser '1', '2', '3', '4' o '5' */

        switch ( opcion )
        {
                      /* Opción 1: Sumar */
            case '1': printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      sum=n1+n2;
                      if(n1+n2==res)
                      printf("\n    Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("\n    Es incorrecto!!");
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      sum=n1+n2;
                      if(n1+n2==res)
                      printf("\n    Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("\n    Es incorrecto!!");
                      break;

                      /* Opción 2: Restar */
            case '2': printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      rest=n1-n2;
                      if(n1-n2==res)
                      printf("  Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("  Es incorrecto!!");
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      rest=n1-n2;
                      if(n1-n2==res)
                      printf("  Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("  Es incorrecto!!");
                      break;

                      /* Opción 3: Multiplicar */
            case '3': printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      mul=n1*n2;
                      if(n1*n2==res)
                      printf("  Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("  Es incorrecto!!");
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      mul=n1*n2;
                      if(n1*n2==res)
                      printf("  Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("  Es incorrecto!!");
                      break;

                      /* Opción 4: División entera */
            case '4': printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      div=n1/n2;
                      if(n1/n2==res)
                      printf("  Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("  Es incorrecto!!");
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n1);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: " );
                      scanf( "%d", &n2);
                      printf( "\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
                      scanf( "%d", &res);
                      div=n1/n2;
                      if(n1/n2==res)
                      printf("  Es correcto!!");
                      else
                      printf("  Es incorrecto!!");
        }

    } while ( opcion != '5' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. C no es lo mismo que C++. Por las cabeceras en uso parece C.

Comment: Ya lo se, solamente puse c++ por el nombre del software que uso

Answer (score 2):

Primero quiero mencionar algunas cosas que puedes hacer para simplificar el código:

- Tienes código repetido.
- Realmente no necesitas tener 4 variables (`sum`, `rest`, `mul`, `div`). No les das un uso diferente.

En el primer punto puedes sacar el código de los mensajes fuera del switch.

Para el segundo punto puedes reemplazar las 4 variables por una sola.

```
int resultadoEsperado = 0;

printf("\n   Introduzca el primer numero: " );
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);
printf("\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
scanf("%d", &resultadoUsuario);

switch (opcion){
    case '1':
        resultadoEsperado = n1 + n2;
    case '2':
        resultadoEsperado = n1 - n2;
    case '3':
        resultadoEsperado = n1 * n2;
    case '4':
        resultadoEsperado = n1 / n2;
}
```

Ahora, en la parte que falta es fácil agregar los contadores `aciertos` y `errores` (recuersa declararlos fuera del ciclo):

```
if (resultadoUsuario == resultadoEsperado){
    printf("Es correcto!!");
    aciertos++;
}
else {
    printf("Es incorrecto!!");
    errores++;
}
```

Solo resta mostrar los aciertos y los errores al terminar.

---

En definitiva, el código quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char opcion;
    int n1, n2, resultadoUsuario;
    int aciertos = 0, errores = 0;

    do {
        printf("\n   >>> CALCULADORA DE 10 EJERCICIOS DE 4 OPERACIONES BASICAS <<<");
        printf("\n\n ----- Eliga la operacion que quiere realizar. ----- ");
        printf("\n\n   1. Suma.", 163);
        printf("\n   2. Resta.", 163);
        printf("\n   3. Multiplicacion.", 163);
        printf("\n   4. Division.", 163);
        printf("\n   5. Salir.\n");

        /* Filtramos la opción elegida por el usuario */
        do {
            printf("\n   Introduzca opci%cn (1-5): ", 162);
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &opcion);

        } while (opcion < '1' || opcion > '5');
        /* La opción sólo puede ser '1', '2', '3', '4' o '5' */

        int resultadoEsperado = 0;

        printf("\n   Introduzca el primer numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &n1);
        printf("\n   Introduzca el segundo numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &n2);
        printf("\n   Introduzca el resultado: ");
        scanf("%d", &resultadoUsuario);

        switch (opcion) {
            case '1':
                resultadoEsperado = n1 + n2;
                break;
            case '2':
                resultadoEsperado = n1 - n2;
                break;
            case '3':
                resultadoEsperado = n1 * n2;
                break;
            case '4':
                resultadoEsperado = n1 / n2;
                break;
        }
        
        if (resultadoUsuario == resultadoEsperado) {
            printf("Es correcto!!");
            aciertos++;
        }
        else {
            printf("Es incorrecto!!");
            errores++;
        }

    } while (opcion != '5');

    printf ("Aciertos: %d\nErrores: %d\n", aciertos, errores);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias buen hombre

Comment: Te faltó incluir la instrucción `break` para cada caso de opción, porque sino el `resultadoEsperado` va a ser un cúmulo de todas las operaciones. @CasillasGonzlezCesarEduardo el `switch` quedaría del modo:  `case '1':  resultadoEsperado = n1 + n2; break;    case '2':  resultadoEsperado = n1 - n2; break; .....` y así para el case 3 y case 4. Además, puedes incluir siempre un `case default` en el que muestre un mensaje de error y el resultado sea igual a 0 por ejemplo. o como Mateo ha hecho, comprobar anteriormente con un `while` que la opción deba estar entre 1 y 5.

Comment: @Londo cierto. Gracias. Por cierto el while ya estaba en el código de OP así que es imposible que la opción no sea una de esas. Por eso no incluí el caso por defecto.

Comment: @Casillas si la pregunta te sirvió marcala cómo respuesta desde el botón de tilde ✓.